# How to exclude or filter password protected posts when using next_post_link() previous_post_link

Tags: loop, pagination, password, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'm using next_post_link() and previous_post_link() in my theme.
I excluded my password protected posts from the loop. They only appear if you enter the URL of this specific post.

But, the problem is that I have next_post_link() and previous_post_link() appearing in every single post. So when I'm in a post that is succeeded or preceded by a password protected post, the password protected post appears in the pagination.

I need to exclude all my password protected post of appearing when using the two aforementioned functions.

I tried using the filters and functions provided in the codex but none of them work the way I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `next_post_link()` allow excludes, with the parameter `excluded_terms`. Add a list of the IDs of the password protected posts to this param.

You get a list of all password protected posts with the follow example via DB select.

`$password_pages = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_password !=''");`

Alternative can you use a hook to filter the password protected post from the loop. Also a example below, that works on the single and page view of the front end.

```
// Filter to hide protected posts
function exclude_protected($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_password = '' ";
}

// Decide where to display them
function exclude_protected_action($query) {
    if( !is_single() && !is_page() && !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'exclude_protected' );
    }
}

// Action to queue the filter at the right time
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_protected_action');
```

Comment: I'm using the first option with excluded_terms. But the thing is, when the post is in between two password protected posts, it shows the password protected posts anyway.

Lets say, post 1 and 3 have password protection, so when I'm in post 2, it shows post 1 and 3.

Comment: And you exclude this also on all templates, there use the next post function? Like the single.php